# Formatting text in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a chat client, and I want the output textbox to make the username and timestamp on the messages **bold** while the rest of the text remains in the default format. How could I possibly do that?

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use a [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why not switch to WPF?

Comment: A browser control would probably work too. Heavier, but the HTML  markup syntax is easier.

Comment: To the guys who marked this as a duplicate, it would be nice if you had linked me to the questions you think this is a duplicate of. Like this, marking it as a duplicate doesn't help me at all.